# .net MAUI showing image from base64 string

Tags: .net, image, base64, maui, .net-maui

I've been trying to show an image from `base64` string. It used to work previously, so I'm pretty sure that the recent updates/patches on `MAUI` have caused this.

Let's say we got a page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSampleCS.Page.HelpPage"
             Title="HelpPage"
             x:Name="This"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail, Source={Reference This}}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And a Code behind:

```
public partial class HelpPage : ContentPage
{
    public static string base64Image = "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";
    public HelpPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ImageSource Thumbnail
    {
        get { return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image))); }
    }
}
```

It should (and used to) display an image, but now, it only displays a blank page.

Implementation like this (`base64` -> `MemoryStream` -> `ImageSource`) used to work previously, but now I'm left scrambling why it no longer works. Are there other solutions for this that would/do work? I know that in `wpf`, you can straight up bind to `byte[]`, but as far as I researched - it's not an option in MAUI.

Comment: I would expect your existing code to work in terms of the `ImageSource` creation, but in the RC-1 of MAUI I've found that images have been broken (compared with the previous release). I would personally just wait for the next release...

Comment: Yeah, it used to work before I updated the maui to the newest version, so I guess I'll take your advice and just move to work on different part of the project and wait until the new release is done. Ty

Answer (score 2):

it is quite simple you have to make an ImageSource

```
MemoryStream stream= new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("the base64 string"));
ImageSource image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

and bind your image source to this ImageSource

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. But I don't want to have infrastructure code in business logic. I thought that it would be convenient to have your own control with the Base64Source property where you could immediately bind base64.

1. First of all, we need to make our own control, the successor of the image:

   ```
    using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    namespace YourAppNameSpace.Controls
    {
        public class ImageBase64 : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image
        {
            public static readonly BindableProperty Base64SourceProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(Base64Source),
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(ImageBase64),
                    string.Empty,
                    propertyChanged: OnBase64SourceChanged);

            public string Base64Source
            {
                set
                {
                    SetValue(Base64SourceProperty, value);
                }
                get
                {
                     return (string)GetValue(Base64SourceProperty); 
                }
            }

            private static void OnBase64SourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String((string)newValue));
                ((Image)bindable).Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Next you on your pages or views you can use this control and bind to your view model base64 string, like this

   ```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="YourAppNameSpace.MainPage"
                 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:YourAppNameSpace.Controls">
        <controls:ImageBase64 Base64Source="{Binding Base64StringPropertyOfYourViewModel}"/>
    </ContentPage>
   ```

Please note that you need to specify a link to the namespace where your control is located (xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:...)

Comment: Does `stream` need to be disposed?

Comment: No! You do not need to dispose, becouse memory stream do not use unmanaged memory. Look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-7.0